# jQuery Ajax request returns error and status 0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

I use this pseudo-class to make Ajax request to server:

```
function RequestManager(url, params, success, error){
    //Save this Ajax configuration
    this._ajaxCall = null;
    this._url= url;
    this._type = params.type;
    this._success = function(){
        alert("ok");
    };
    this._error = function(){
        alert("ko");
    };
}

RequestManager.prototype = {
    require : function(text){
        var self = this;
        this._ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url: this._url,
            type: this._type,
            data: text,
            success: function(xmlResponse){
                var responseArray = [];
                var response = _extractElements(xmlResponse, arrayResponse);
                self._success(response);
            },
            error: self._error,
            complete : function(xhr, statusText){
                alert(xhr.status);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

This is PHP that will be loaded:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //Do something
    $done = true;

    $response = buildXML($done);
    $xmlString = $response->saveXML();
    echo $xmlString;

    function buildXML ($done){
        $response = new SimpleXMLElement("<response></response>");
        if($done){
            $response->addChild('outcome','ok');
        }
        else {
            $response->addChild('outcome', 'ko');
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

When I instantiate a new object, and I use it to load a request, it always return to me error, and status code is 0. The server correctly generates an XML document. Why I can't get a correct 200 code back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this happens on your second call to `require`, it's because the call to `abort()` results in your callback being called with a status code of 0. You should later get the correct result for the second request.

In jQuery 1.4 there's also a bug where your `success` callback is called after an aborted request. See [my answer to *Request periodically coming back empty under race conditions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630274/request-periodically-coming-back-empty-under-race-conditions/2630450#2630450).

Unrelated to this issue, there are variables in your code (`timer` and `ajaxCall`) that seem to be referenced both with and without a leading underscore.

Comment: Ok, the problem was in another block of code, anyway your info are useful. Thanks